# MySQL dropping all indexes from table

Tags: mysql, indexing, alter-table

I have a MySQL database that runs for some time now with many changes on it. Lately I looked over it and I noticed that in some cases I have doubled the index on the same field. Some Indexes are missing, and in general there is a huge mess in all the indexes.

I wants to drop all indexes from a table. Later on I have a prepared script that will run `ALTER TABLE` and add the relevant indexes.

Is there a way to drop all indexes from a table?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you have phpmyadmin or any similar tool you can do that very easily graphically.

Or for every index do something like

```
ALTER TABLE  `table` DROP INDEX  `NameIndex`
```

You can get the indexes with

```
SHOW INDEX FROM `table`
```

Comment: You can also drop more than one index in one query, e.g. `ALTER TABLE table DROP INDEX first, DROP INDEX second, DROP INDEX third` etc..

Comment: How is it "very easy" in phpMyAdmin?

Answer (score 28):

Simple script:

```
-- list all non-unique indexes
SELECT table_name AS `Table`,
       index_name AS `Index`,
       GROUP_CONCAT(column_name ORDER BY seq_in_index) AS `Columns`
FROM information_schema.statistics
WHERE NON_UNIQUE = 1 AND table_schema = 'mydatabase' AND table_name = 'mytable'
GROUP BY 1,2;

-- drop all non-unique indexes
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len=10240;

SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ', `Table`, ' DROP INDEX ', GROUP_CONCAT(`Index` SEPARATOR ', DROP INDEX '),';' )
FROM (
SELECT table_name AS `Table`,
       index_name AS `Index`
FROM information_schema.statistics
WHERE NON_UNIQUE = 1 AND table_schema = 'mydatabase' AND table_name = 'mytable'
GROUP BY `Table`, `Index`) AS tmp
GROUP BY `Table`;

-- add all non-unique indexes , WITHOUT index length spec
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len=10240;
SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ', `Table`, ' ADD INDEX ', GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(`Index`, '(', `Columns`, ')') SEPARATOR ',\n ADD INDEX ') )
FROM (
SELECT table_name AS `Table`,
       index_name AS `Index`,
        GROUP_CONCAT(column_name ORDER BY seq_in_index) AS `Columns`
FROM information_schema.statistics
WHERE NON_UNIQUE = 1 AND table_schema = 'mydatabase' AND table_name = 'mytable'
GROUP BY `Table`, `Index`) AS tmp
GROUP BY `Table`;
```

Comment: If you're slow on the uptake like me, this script generates alter table statements that you have to then run.  Once I stopped being stupid, it works well.

Comment: years later this has been very useful to clean up a database after removing a table prefix across the board

Comment: I was about to complain that it doesn't work, but then I've realized that it generates the query, not executes. That's some higher level of scripting!
I should have read the comments :)

Comment: Thank you!! It also took me a moment to understand that these SQL statements "generate" an output and then have to be executed.

It can be executed automatically by adding after the select clause:
INTO @some_named_var;

and after the end of the query "drop index statement generator" selected we execute
PREPARE sql_query FROM @some_named_var;
EXECUTE sql_query;

and boom! no more indexes, it is not necessary to know the names of the indexes. We directly eliminate according to the conditions of the "statement generator" query

Answer (score 7):

In Ruby on Rails I do this:

```
indexes = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SHOW INDEX FROM tablename")
indexes.each do |index|
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("ALTER TABLE tablename DROP INDEX #{index[2]};")
end
```

Answer (score 4):

no there isnt a command.
you can however write a script that shows all databases, shows all tables inside thowe databases, shows all indexes inside those tables and drops them all.
but i'n not gonna write that for you if you don't start accepting some answers.
you can also use phpmyadmin or another graphical tool to select this neat "check all" box for every table.

Comment: first thanks for the answer. second i am accepting answers as the answer really answers and gives solution for the question. anyhow i can write the script myself but thanks for offering. wish there would be a way to do so though (dropping all indexes).

Comment: okay... thats right. 54% just looked a bit few to me but if its like this its totally okay. loic posted the command to list indexes, good luck with your script