# MySQL command to drop all non-primary indexes of a table

Tags: php, mysql, indexing, sql-drop

Is there a MySQL command that can drop all the extra indexes except for the first one in a single table thus keeping only the primary index?

I can drop the second **Post_Date** index using the following MySQL command, but I am having problems dropping all the rest of them.

```
mysql_query("ALTER TABLE $TableName DROP INDEX Post_Date");
```

The extra **Post_Date** and **Post_Date_x** indexes are created in the beginning of the script, so I want to delete them at the end of the script using a MySQL command at the end of the script.

Keep in mind that **_x** in **Post_Date_x** and vary and could go from 1 to 10, or from 1 to 100. So a Loop or IF statement may be needed.

The MySQL command will be part of a PHP script

Thank you for your time.

```
Action  Keyname Type    Unique  Packed  Column  Cardinality Collation   Null    Comment
 Edit    Drop   PRIMARY BTREE   Yes No  id  830 A       
 Edit    Drop   Post_Date   BTREE   Yes No  Post_Date   830 A       
 Edit    Drop   Post_Date_2 BTREE   Yes No  Post_Date   830 A       
 Edit    Drop   Post_Date_3 BTREE   Yes No  Post_Date   830 A       
 Edit    Drop   Post_Date_4 BTREE   Yes No  Post_Date   830 A       
 Edit    Drop   Post_Date_5 BTREE   Yes No  Post_Date   830 A       
 Edit    Drop   Post_Date_6 BTREE   Yes No  Post_Date   830 A       
 Edit    Drop   Post_Date_7 BTREE   Yes No  Post_Date   830 A       
 Edit    Drop   Post_Date_8 BTREE   Yes No  Post_Date   830 A
```

Comment: Check my answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/a/16200754/757850

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it -

```
$res = mysql_query("SHOW INDEX FROM `$TableName` WHERE `Key_name` LIKE 'Post_Date%'");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($res)) {
    mysql_query("DROP INDEX `{$row->Key_name}` ON `{$row->Table}`") or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but it did not work. I copied the code into my PHP script and did not get errors when ran, but it did not drop any indexes.

Comment: The SHOW INDEX FROM `$TableName` WHERE `Key_name` LIKE 'Post_Date%' part displays all the indexes, but the while loop does not drop them.

Comment: There was an error in my example. I have corrected it and added some debug code.

Comment: It works great. Thank you so much. I really appreciate it. By the way, would you happen to know how to determine the number of indexes in the table, because I would only need to run this script if the number of indexes is greater than 1. For example, if (number of indexes > 1) {run the script}

Comment: It is not worth doing a separate check. This will only do anything if the relevant indices exist. Please remember to accept the answer that answers your question. Just click on the tick next to your preferred answer.

Comment: I should have asked how and why do you end up with the duplicate indices in the first place. It would be better to solve that problem as opposed to having to delete them.

Comment: The following duplicate-like post describes the problem I had, but you were the only one that figured it out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10180653/is-there-a-mysql-command-drop-all-indexes-except-primary-index

Comment: After reading the other post I think you might want to check out [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html). You can then have the unique key in place all the time and avoid this whole de-duplicating process. Or possibly just using INSERT IGNORE so that it skips the records that already exist.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but there is no MySQL comand for `ALTER TABLE ny_table DROP ALL INDEXES EXCEPT PRIMARY KEY`.

You would have to create a specific name for each index as it was created, and then create a loop to individually run an `ALTER TABLE ... DROP INDEX` SQL command for each index using the same names.

Note also that creating indexes is rather expensive - unless you are doing > ~200 queries that are optimized by the index, creating and deleting the index probably takes more time than is saved by using them.

Comment: Well is there a Mysql command to retrieve **just** the keynames? This way I can write a loop to drop them. I tried $posting_date = 'Post_Date_'.$i; mysql_query("SHOW INDEX FROM $TableName WHERE KEY_NAME = '$posting_date'"); but that does not work

Comment: @sammy, I don't know why that query doesn't work for you.  It works for me. `create table foo (a int, b int); create index idx1 on foo (a); create index idx2 on foo (b); show index from foo where Key_name='idx1';`

Comment: @Keith Randall, I don't understand the query you are talking about. I know how to drop individual indexes, but I would like to have a loop statement that would do it. I tried     for($i = 1; ; $i++) {
      $posting_date = 'Post_Date_'.$i;
      $index_exists = mysql_query("SHOW INDEX FROM $TableName WHERE KEY_NAME = '$posting_date'");
      if($index_exists > 0) {mysql_query("ALTER TABLE $TableName DROP INDEX $posting_date");} else {break;}
    } but it fails